# Setting up a cmake project properly with thirdparty

Tags: cmake

I am trying to get better on `CMake`. Currently I try to build a toy example that is using OpenCV that I have built from source and installed in a directory called thirdparty.

I can run build

`cmake ..`
`cmake --build .`
`cmake --install . --prefix ../tmp`

In build I can run `./app/TestOpenCV` and get a 3x4 zero matrix as output.

If I run `../tmp/bin/TestOpenCV` I get
`Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gapi.406.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libopencv_gapi.406.dylib' (no such file)`

It appears that the linking is not working appropriately when I install the binary. I.e. it searching for the libraries in the wrong location. How can I make this work?

I have the following structure

```
TestCMake 
   CMakeLists.txt
              app
                 TestOpenCV.cpp
                 CMakeLists.txt

              thirdparty
                 installdir
                     opencv_mac
                         bin
                         include
                         lib
                         share
```

TopLevel `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "thirdparty/installdir/opencv_mac/lib/cmake/opencv4/" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

include_directories(SYSTEM ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(app)
```

App level CMakeLists

```
add_executable(TestOpenCV TestOpenCV.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TestOpenCV ${OpenCV_LIBS})

install(TARGETS TestOpenCV
        DESTINATION bin)
```

How can I make the binary work after installing it?

Comment: In the **build** tree, all executables and shared libraries refers to the other libraries by their **absolute paths**. This is why your executable correctly works in the build tree. When **install** executables and shared libraries, CMake strips out absolute paths from them, so [RPATH mechanism](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) comes to play. You need either to embed information about location of `libopencv_gapi.406.dylib` library into the executable (in `CMakeLists.txt`), or to make the `ld` loader be aware of that location.

Comment: How do I embed information about the location of the libs in CMakeLists?

Comment: Tsyvarev linked you to a wiki. read the wiki 